# The word "Adobe" in funny colour in WinEdt

Tags: winedt

It seems like some words are highlighted automatically in a different colour in WinEdt.

Is there anyone that can explain this?

Is there any setting regarding which words to highlight in which colour?

An example regarding the word "Adobe" in the screenshot below:

[image: The word "Adobe" highlighted in funny colour in WinEdt]

Comment: Yes, Adobe is in a list in keywords.ini which gets a special color (in the same list are words like CTAN or dvips). If you don't like this you can adapt the highlighting.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer What is the purpose with this besides being "cool"?

Comment: Ask the author on the winedt mailing list if you want to know why he did it.